# why gdb don't load libdl over sharedlibrady ? and heaptrack not working

Tags: c++, gdb, shared-libraries, dll-injection

I use Ubuntu 14.04

I try using https://github.com/KDE/heaptrack for detect memory leaks in my running C++ program

when heaptrack shell script running

```
 gdb --batch-silent -n -iex="set auto-solib-add off" -p $pid \
   --eval-command="sharedlibrary libdl" \
   --eval-command="call (void) dlmopen(0x00, \"$LIBHEAPTRACK_INJECT\", 0x002)" \
   --eval-command="sharedlibrary libheaptrack_inject" \
   --eval-command="call (void) heaptrack_inject(\"$pipe\")" \
   --eval-command="detach"
```

i see following error messages

```
No symbol "dlmopen" in current context.
No symbol "heaptrack_inject" in current context.
```

and when i run gdb manually

```
gdb -p XXX
(gdb) sharedlibrary libdl
```

i see other error message

```
No loaded shared libraries match the pattern `libdl'.
```

but libdl.so exists in my filesystem

```
# find / -name libdl*.so
/usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
```

Why gdb don't load libdl over sharedlibrary command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why gdb don't load libdl over sharedlibrary command ?

This message:

```
No loaded shared libraries match the pattern `libdl'.
```

means that your inferior (being debugged) process does not link against `libdl`. You can find *all* libraries that your inferior has with `(gdb) info shared`, and confirm that `libdl` is not among them.

GDB does not by itself modify the set of loaded libraries.

> `find / -name libdl*.so`

This is *irrelevant*. The `libdl.so` exists, but that doesn't mean that every process loads it (your process *doesn't*).